# Locked when call xarray save_mfdataset() or to_netcdf() in parallel

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, netcdf, python-xarray

I have a multithreading code that creates some nc files in parallel. All the threads finish in a function that uses the xarray xr.save_mfdataset() and I realize that the files are created in serial, not in parallel, so they are waiting to be written one after another.

It seems that some locks should be into the save method. Does anyone know how to disable this kind of locks to write netcdf files in parallel?

Thanks!